# ReactNativePermissions pod spec not found

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

So I'm trying to run an iOS app project that is written in react-native, after cloning and npm install, I encountered a problem while trying to pod install in iOS folder.

This is the error:

[!] No podspec found for `ReactNativePermissions` in `../node_modules/react-native-permissions`

due to:

pod 'ReactNativePermissions', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-permissions'

I tried to search but couldn't find any working solution, can anyone help me with this?

React-native version: 2.0.1
React-native-permission: version 2.0.8

So this was actually the problem. One of the thing I realised is that, people usually do something like "npm install library" but didn't specify the version. What happens is that it becomes "^version" in the package.json and later on after years, when I run npm install, I get the newer versions and it's not compatible so be sure to check your version guys.

Comment: Did you run ‘pod install’ from iOS folder?

Comment: Yes i did, i even tried to comment out that line and there will he no errors while trying to pod install but i encoutered permission errors in app due to commenting out that line.

Comment: Please specify the version of `react-native` and `react-native-permission`

Comment: React-native version 2.0.1
React-native-permission version 2.0.8

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Another update**
Documentation has been updated for 3.0.0+

Refer to https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-permissions/issues/547#issuecomment-735216465

**Update**

I ran into this issue again, I noticed yarn add `react-native-permissions` installed 3.0.0-beta.2 version, which doesn't have the podspecs within the `permissions_path`. I updated package.json to have latest 2+ version (2.2.2 at the time) to resolve.

[image]

**Prior**

The :path should have double quotes not single.

For example

`pod 'Permission-Camera', :path => '#{permissions_path}/Camera.podspec'`

Should be

`pod 'Permission-Camera', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Camera.podspec"`

Comment: I did what @Dylan w mentioned above. Still had same issue. But, then i reinstalled the npm packages. That solved my problem.

Comment: One of the thing I realised is that, people usually do something like "npm install library" but didn't specify the version. What happens is that it becomes "^version" in the package.json and later on after years, when people run npm install, they get newer versions and it's not compatible so be sure to check your version guys.

Answer (score 22):

Update:

For react-native-permissions v3.0.1^, the paths got changed to `#{permissions_path}/<ModuleName>/Permission-<ModuleName>.podspec`

For the exact path, try (from project root):

```
cd node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios/
```

You'll get all available module names, `cd <ModuleName>` and your '.podspec' file should be there.

For me, the problem is from the path. I changed the path to:

```
pod 'Permission-Camera', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Camera/Permission-Camera.podspec"
```

then it worked.

Answer (score 7):

target yourProject do:

```
  permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'
  pod 'Permission-Camera', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Camera/Permission-Camera.podspec"
```

Answer (score 4):

My problem was that the target didn't have the .podspec`

I had

```
pod 'Permission-Calendars', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Calendars"
```

instead of

```
pod 'Permission-Calendars', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Calendars.podspec"
```

Answer (score 1):

First add this to your pod file dependencies place:

```
target 'Bverify' do
  # Pods for your project name
```

........

```
permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'
  pod 'Permission-Camera', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Camera.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-MediaLibrary', :path => "#{permissions_path}/MediaLibrary.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-PhotoLibrary', :path => "#{permissions_path}/PhotoLibrary.podspec"
```

.......

You need to install the permissions before pod install :

run command:

```
npm i react-native-permissions
```

and then at the end:

cd ios
pod install

Answer (score 1):

[image: You can the difference with the latest path, they moved pod files into respective modules, hence below changes are required]
You can the difference with the latest path, they moved pod files into respective modules, hence below changes are required

Answer (score 1):

**2022 Fix:**

React Native Permissions Library is updated which resolves this issue in the latest version. So all you need to do is to run the command

`npm install react-native-permissions`

or

`yarn add react-native-permissions`

or try running

`yarn add react-native-permissions@latest`

At the time of writing this it upgraded my version to

```
"react-native-permissions": "^3.3.1"
```

This issue occurred on `3.0.0` but was solved in `3.0.4`

You can also confirm that the file is found in this folder:

[image]

Happy hacking!

Answer (score 0):

I have 3.6.0 installed and saw this same error for `Permission-AppTrackingTransparency` so removed the `.podspec` from podfile as per this answer and it worked:
[https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-permissions/issues/360#:~:text=6%20Jan%202021-,%40hemantsati95%20when%20you%20use%20the%203.0.0%20release%20you%20have%20to%20remove%20the%20%22.podspec%22%20extensions%20in%20your%20Podfile.,-https%3A//github.com](https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-permissions/issues/360#:%7E:text=6%20Jan%202021-,%40hemantsati95%20when%20you%20use%20the%203.0.0%20release%20you%20have%20to%20remove%20the%20%22.podspec%22%20extensions%20in%20your%20Podfile.,-https%3A//github.com)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the suggested implementation from https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-permissions

For react-native >= 0.72

Replace this

```
require Pod::Executable.execute_command('node', ['-p',
  'require.resolve(
    "react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb",
    {paths: [process.argv[1]]},
  )', __dir__]).strip
```

With below lines of code

```
def node_require(script)
  # Resolve script with node to allow for hoisting
  require Pod::Executable.execute_command('node', ['-p',
    "require.resolve(
      '#{script}',
      {paths: [process.argv[1]]},
    )", __dir__]).strip
end

node_require('react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb')
node_require('react-native-permissions/scripts/setup.rb')
```

and add a `setup_permissions` call with the wanted permissions:

```
# …

platform :ios, min_ios_version_supported
prepare_react_native_project!

# ⬇️ uncomment wanted permissions
setup_permissions([
  # 'AppTrackingTransparency',
  # 'Bluetooth',
  # 'Calendars',
  # 'CalendarsWriteOnly',
  # 'Camera',
  # 'Contacts',
  # 'FaceID',
  # 'LocationAccuracy',
  # 'LocationAlways',
  # 'LocationWhenInUse',
  # 'MediaLibrary',
  # 'Microphone',
  # 'Motion',
  # 'Notifications',
  # 'PhotoLibrary',
  # 'PhotoLibraryAddOnly',
  # 'Reminders',
  # 'Siri',
  # 'SpeechRecognition',
  # 'StoreKit',
])

# …
```

Answer (score 0):

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40jxY.png)

check if this file is there, if not do npm i and than cd ios && pod install.